# How to get username from users table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the Controller code I have

```
public function index()
{
    $ajobs = Job::all();
    
    return view('jobs_all', ['jobs' => $ajobs]);
}
```

This shows all my Table Data. I have stored user id as another column named `created_by`
In the View, I get value by ID, how how can I get the Username from Users table.

```
@foreach ($jobs as $ajob)
    {{ $ajob->created_by }}  //Here instead of UserID, how can i get Username by matching the UserID with UsersTable ?
@endforeach
```

Comment: can post job table. add foreignId user .

Answer (score 1):

- Add next method to your "Job" model:

```
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
```

- now you can add ORM param "with" to your method "index":

```
public function index() {
$ajobs = Job::with('user')
          ->all();
    
return view('jobs_all', ['jobs' => $ajobs]); }
```

- now we have access to **user model** fields, and you can show them this way:

```
@foreach($jobs as $ajob)
    {{ $ajob->user->name }} 
@endforeach
```

More info about laravel relations here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel eloquent [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship. in your `Job` model add the following method.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    //assuming your user model name is User and both models are in the same namespace. if not, adjust according to your structure. 
}
```

and then you can use this relationship to get the user name like

```
@foreach ($jobs as $ajob)
    {{ $ajob->user->name }}
    //name is the column name from the user table. change if necessary.
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relations but in fast way on your situation you can join your tables:

```
$user_id = DB::table('jobs')
    ->select('users.id')
    ->join('jobs', 'jobs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=> add on your job table as foreginId user

$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->foreignId('created_by')->constrained('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');


**That Function add on job model**

public function getCreatedAttribute()
    {
        return ucfirst($this->user->name);
    }

=>relationship add on job table

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id','created_by');
    
}

=>created display your user name

@foreach ($jobs as $ajob)
    {{ $ajob->created}}
@endforeach

=>listing controller

public function index() {
$jobs = Job::with(['user']);
    
return view('jobs_all', compact('jobs')); }
```